# Rectangles in pygame

Tags: pygame

Can you change the length of one side of a rectangle in pygame?

For example:

```
img = pygame.image.load('image.gif')
rect = img.get_rect()
```

In that example I load an image and create a rectangle around it. With that in mind could I, for instance, change the length of the bottom of the rect with out it changing any other sides of the rectangle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PyGames [Rect objects](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) to **store rectangular coordinates**.

As @Tehsmeely mentioned, there are a number of so-called **virtual attributes** which can be used to **move or align a Rect object** in your game:

[image: Virtual Attributes of a PyGame Rect Object]

When you want to load an image form a file into your game the [`pygame.image.load()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load) function **returns a new Surface object** which is like your main screen surface. You can [blit](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) (i.e. copy) this new surface object onto any other surface you want by using the `.blit()` method:

- The first argument of `.blit()` is the **source surface**.
- The second argument can either be pair of **coordinates representing the upper left corner of the source surface**
   or **a Pygame Rect object where the topleft corner of the rectangle will be used as the position for the blit**. 
  The size of the destination rectangle **does not affect the blit**.

This means you can change the length of the bottom of your `rect`:

```
rect.width= 100
```

but this will not affect the size of your `img`.

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html

A rect is simply a data structure for these things, and you can set any of the below properties of a rect

```
x,y
top, left, bottom, right
topleft, bottomleft, topright, bottomright
midtop, midleft, midbottom, midright
center, centerx, centery
size, width, height
w,h
```

just make a new rect in python shell and have a play, you can make Rects themselves

```
import pygame
rect = pygame.Rect((10,10),(20,20))
print rect.height
>>20
rect.height = 30
print rect.height
>>30
```

Edit:
This won't effect the image you loaded with regards to how it appears, to draw to a screen you need a surface and a rect, if you want to modify the image you need to change the surface. Alternatively stretching you loaded imaged by drawing to an increased rect WILL work, check out the explanation for Surface.blit, http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit

Comment: will this change the position of the image on the screen?

Comment: The position of the rect is defined in the properties that sound like it, such as "topleft", which define the position of the top left of the rect. You only need to set one of these, it will work the rest out for you