# Centering space ship at bottom of screen in Alien Invasion from Python Crash Course by Eric Matthes

Tags: python

I have done the Alien Invasion project from Python Crash Course.  I added in the ability to move up and down as well as left and right.  However, when I move up and hit the aliens 3 times it simply redraws the aliens and doesn't reset the ship back to the bottom center where it began when the game started.  I have tried to update the center_ship() function but nothing I do works.  Here is my code:

```
def ship_hit(ai_settings, stats, sb, screen, ship, aliens, bullets):
    """Respond to ship being hit by alien."""
    if stats.ships_left > 0:
        #Decrement ships left
        stats.ships_left -= 1

        #update scoreboard
        sb.prep_ships()

        #Empty list of aliens and bullets
        aliens.empty()
        bullets.empty()

        #Create a new fleet and center the ship
        create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens)
        ship.center_ship()

        #Pause
        sleep(0.5)

    else:
        stats.game_active = False
        pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)
        ship.center_ship()
```

And the Ship class:

```
class Ship(Sprite):

    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):
        """Initialize the ship and it's starting position"""
        super(Ship, self).__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings

        #Load the ship image and get its rect.
        self.image = pygame.image.load('ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

        #Start each new ship at the bottom center of the screen
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom

        #Store a decimal value for the ship's center
        self.center = float(self.rect.centerx)
        self.centery = float(self.rect.centery)
        self.bottom = float(self.rect.bottom)

        #Movement flag
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False
        self.moving_up = False
        self.moving_down = False

    def update(self):
        """Update ship's position based on movement flag"""
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.center += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
            self.center -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
        if self.moving_up and self.rect.top > 0:
            self.centery -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
        if self.moving_down and self.rect.bottom < self.screen_rect.bottom:
            self.centery += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor

        #Update rect from self.center
        self.rect.centerx = self.center
        self.rect.centery = self.centery


    def blitme(self):
        """Draw the ship at it's current location"""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def center_ship(self):
        """Center the ship on the screen"""
        self.center = self.screen_rect.bottom
```

Comment: Note that your code already has a comment that says `#Start each new ship at the bottom center of the screen`

Answer (score 0):

Your `center_ship()` method looks different than the `center_ship()` method from the [book's resources](https://github.com/ehmatthes/pcc_2e/blob/master/chapter_13/ending_the_game/ship.py).

Here's a good [illustration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29584561/rectangles-in-pygame) of the various rect attributes you can use for positioning objects on a pygame screen. Let's look at this line:

```
self.center = self.screen_rect.bottom
```

This is setting an attribute of `ship`, `self.center`, equal to the y-value of the bottom of the screen. `self.center` is not a rect attribute; it's just a variable associated with the `Ship` object.